# Vue.js 3 v-model on form element got undefined type error on missing data from REST Call

Tags: rest, nosql, vuejs3

Coming from Svelte and being new to Vue.js 3, I encounter a situation that I found a little bit confusing. This is a quite simple scenario that you will get into all the time when dealing with REST call on no-sql backend... partial data set. Let me explain with this simple example:

```
<template>
<div v-if="info">
  <form>
    <input type="text" v-model="info.firstname">
    <input type="text" v-model="info.lastname">
    <input type="text" v-model="info.address.street">
    <input type="text" v-model="info.address.city">
    <input type="text" v-model="info.address.postalCode">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
  </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    //Imagine a rest call here...
    this.info = {
      firstname: "Micheal",
      lastname: "Jordan",
    }
  }, 
  data() {
    return {
      info: {
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        address: {
          city: '',
          street: '',
          postalCode: ''
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This will get you a " Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $data.info.address is undefined " because of the missing address block. But functionally speaking, the address is optional and will not be return if use MongoDB or DynamoDB backend. And has I said at the beginning, in Svelte, I simply apply a spread operator on my info object and the "missing" data is no concern. If I add the missing address section in my "simulated" API call, everythings fine.

What am I missing here?! (remember I'm starting to learn Vue here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well... I don't why I didn't think of it faster...

```
....
    this.info = {...this.info,
      firstname: "Micheal",
      lastname: "Jordan",
    }
....
```

Simply use the spread operator! :-)